# With the following joint pmf values, how would I find the expected value of a variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I have this dataset:

$$y\\
x \begin{matrix}
   &  0  &  1  &  2  &  3 \\ \hline
0  &  .08  &  .07  &  .04  &  .00 \\
1  &  .06  &  .15  &  .05  &  .04 \\
2  &  .05  &  .04  &  .10  &  .06 \\
3  &  .00  &  .03  &  .04  &  .07 \\
4  &  .00  &  .01  &  .05  &  .06 
\end{matrix}$$

How would I calculate $E(X-Y)$ and then $E(X)$ like my textbook asks me to?

Comment: For $E(X-Y)$, use the fact that expectation is linear. Then, compute $E(X)=\sum_{n=0}^4 n\cdot P(X=n)$.